# Manhua where the main character realizes that animals can be slaughtered to gain levels

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation, webcomics

I am looking for a manhua where the main character is in a modern world where people have superpowers to fight monsters in dungeons. The main character gets a leveling up system where, in order to level up, he has to kill 1,000 ants to become level one. An old man and his grandson call him crazy for applying bug spray everywhere. In the second chapter he realizes that you can earn cash while leveling up, so later on he buys chickens to level up and gain money. In the 4th or 8th chapter he starts working at a slaughterhouse so he can gain more levels and kills a one-eyed wolf too.
It was in English.

Comment: Not a manhwa, but interestingly, https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/rpg-system-gamer-like-multiverse-oc.739300/ also has killing ants as a first quest.

Comment: Was this in English? The description for "Invincible Combat System" / 无敌战斗力系统 mentions killing ants for level ups, but I can't find any English chapters.

Comment: @qazmlpok I have found English chapters, albeit scanlated in an amateurish way involving textboxes being pasted in.